# Show that $A^{\dagger^{\dagger}} = A $

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

How do we show that $A^{\dagger^{\dagger}} = A $ without assuming $A$ to be a  explicit matrix. That is, given a linear operator $A$, let us define $A^\dagger$ to be a unique operator such that $\langle A^\dagger u \mid v \rangle  = \langle u\mid A v \rangle $ (standard inner product in Hilbert space) for any vectors $u$ and $v$. How can we prove that using this definition alone.

Comment: Can someone explain "$\dagger$" to me?

Comment: @jasoncube, see [conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) and [Hermitian adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint).

Comment: $A^*$ is a good notation to represent the adjoint of $A$. Because, in linear algebra $A^\dagger$ is used for moore-penrose inverse generally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the definition, $A^{\dagger\dagger}$ is the unique linear operator such that
$$\langle A^{\dagger\dagger}u\mid v\rangle = \langle u\mid A^\dagger v\rangle = \overline{\langle A^\dagger v\mid u\rangle} = \overline{\langle v\mid Au\rangle} = \overline{\overline{\langle Au\mid v\rangle}} = \langle Au\mid v\rangle$$
for all vectors $u$ and $v$, so...